# Using printf to call an image

Tags: php, html, css, wordpress, printf

I have the following snippet for calling post author, time and categories

```
<?php
        printf( __( '<span>%s</span> by %s in %s', 'xxxx' ),
            get_the_time( 'M j' ),
            et_get_the_author_posts_link(),
            get_the_category_list( ', ' )
        );
?>
```

I would like to replace the "by" (before author) and "in" (befor categories) with an image

I have tried several ways in call the image but failed. Any help on this on would be great.

Thanks

Comment: What were the several ways you tried?

Comment: can you not replace `et_get_the...` and `get_the_cate...` with strings containing image code?

Comment: Would not `'<span>%s</span> <img src="by.png"> %s <img src="in.png"> %s', 'xxxx'` instead of `'<span>%s</span> by %s in %s', 'xxxx'` cut it?

Comment: Thanks, i tried that, but don't work

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
    $img = '<img src="/images/myimage.png" alt="Some Image" />';
    printf( __( '<span>%s</span> %s %s in %s', 'xxxx' ),
    $img,
        get_the_time( 'M j' ),
        et_get_the_author_posts_link(),
        get_the_category_list( ', ' )
    );
```

Comment: Thanks for the fast reply but the following placed the (alt="Some Image") only but not the image